# BeautifulSoup scraping binance BTC_USDT page and not every <div> is found

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape from the BTC_USDT page from Binance.

From the resulting html I couldn't find the  tags that I am looking for.

For eg: The live price is under <div class="subPrice css-4lmq3e", it is found when inspected but not when scraped. Although I could find some other  tags like id="__APP".

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
url = "https://www.binance.com/en/trade/BTC_USDT?type=spot"
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
div = soup.find("div", {"class" : "subPrice css-4lmq3e"})
content = f'Content : {str(div)}'
print(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

you get can the current price of BTC_USDT from binance using there API.

https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCUSDT

https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md